# Fatal error in toast.exe when compiling app.js

Tags: node.js, github, gruntjs

I have never seen this one before:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
Fatal error: spawn C:\Users\DonTron\Documents\GitHub\dev-thaihome\api\node_modules\grunt-notify\bin\toaster\toast.exe ENOENT
Completed in 2.163s at Tue May 30 2017 20:52:12 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time) - Waiting...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
```

Anyone knows what it is and how I should deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error was that I forgot to install grunt-notify

This did the trick

```
npm uninstall grunt-notify 
npm install grunt-notify
```

1